# With Rabbitmq as broker does celery workers works on push api or pull api?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

Reading about consumers from the Rabbitmq docs [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#consumers) revealed that there are two possible ways a consumer gets messages to process:

> Storing messages in queues is useless unless applications can consume
> them. In the AMQP 0-9-1 Model, there are two ways for applications to
> do this:
>
> ```
> Have messages delivered to them ("push API")
> Fetch messages as needed ("pull API")
> ```
>
> With the "push API", applications have to indicate interest in
> consuming messages from a particular queue. When they do so, we say
> that they register a consumer or, simply put, subscribe to a queue.

I was just wondering:

1. Which way celery workers work?
2. Is there a way to choose/change the way?

Didn't find anything specific about this in Celery docs.

Comment: Taking into account how RabbitMQ works I'd say it's push.

Comment: I was about to post the same question :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Celery uses the push method, based on the fact that it registers consumers to queues, and that it maintains long-lived connections to the broker.
2. No, as far as I can tell the pull method was never really accommodated in Celery's design.

The RabbitMQ doc [has been updated](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-website/commit/efe0cd78c205fd50a7f1f49ce27fed9f7c02b0b3) (after this question was asked) to note that the push method is the strongly recommended option, and that the pull/polling method is “highly inefficient and should be avoided in most cases”. In a [related doc](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#fetching), it says:

> Fetching messages one by one is **highly discouraged** as it is **very inefficient** compared to regular long-lived consumers. As with any polling-based algorithm, it will be **extremely wasteful** in systems where message publishing is sporadic and queues can stay empty for prolonged periods of time.

This claim about extreme wastefulness probably doesn't hold when the tasks/messages are not needed on a real-time basis, such that the queue can just be polled and drained at intervals on the order of hours or even less frequently, though a solution like Celery/RabbitMQ is probably overkill for such use cases in the first place.

I've taken a quick (and limited) tour of Celery's source code and I can say that a big part of its architecture seems to simply assume that the push method is what's being used. There are complex components like heartbeat mechanisms that make the system more robust in the context of long-running operation and inevitable network failures; these components simply are not needed in the pull/polling mode.